# Can't access computer by IP or name over network

Tags: node.js, ip

I've been combing the web searching for an answer to my question, namely why I can't access my computer running a NodeJS application locally using my IP address or host name from another device.

`listen(80, 'my ipv4 address')`

Here's what I've tried:
turning off firewalls altogether on private networks,
allowing network discovery on both computers (it was already on),
listening to my IPV4 address through port 80,
double-checking both devices were going through the same router,
and trying to access my web app through my host name specified in ipconfig

I can access my computer locally perfectly fine (like you'd expect) but when I try to access it from another computer it tells me the site can't be reached and took too long to respond.

Does anyone have any answers to this question?

Comment: What's your computer OS?  Perhaps a local firewall or malware program?  Can you ping the IP address from the other computer?  Can you traceroute the IP address?

Comment: I'm using windows 10. I can attempt to ping from the other computer, but it times out, which makes me think this is an issue with a firewall running on my computer. Attempting to traceroute from another computer also times out.

Comment: Windows 10 clients all have a local firewall by default that will prevent incoming connections to your server.  You will need to make an exception for that process/port you're running.  Some info on how to do that: http://www.tomshardware.com/faq/id-3114787/open-firewall-ports-windows.html

Comment: Thank you! That worked. Apparently the network I was on was considered a public network when it wasn't.

Comment: Also, unless you are doing something very specific, don't specify a host parameter to the listen call. Just pass the port number to enable listening for incoming connections on all adapters. `myServer.listen(80);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I post my comment as an answer since it led to your solution:

Windows 10 clients all have a local firewall by default that will prevent incoming connections to your server. You will need to make an exception for that process/port you're running. Some info on how to do that here: http://www.tomshardware.com/faq/id-3114787/open-firewall-ports-windows.html

Here are the general steps from that article:

**Open firewall ports in Windows 10**

You can manually permit a program to access the internet by opening a firewall port. You will need to know what port it uses and the protocol to make this work.

1. Navigate to Control Panel, System and Security and Windows Firewall.
2. Select Advanced settings and highlight Inbound Rules in the left pane.
3. Right click Inbound Rules and select New Rule.
4. Add the port you need to open and click Next.
5. Add the protocol (TCP or UDP) and the port number into the next window and click Next.
6. Select Allow the connection in the next window and hit Next.
7. Select the network type as you see fit and click Next.
8. Name the rule something meaningful and click Finish.